# Is there a better way to create a dynamically generated jQuery Mobile Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using the jQuery dialog widget to display returned JSON data from the server. The only way  I seem to be able to get this to work seems a bit 'hacky'. I have to create an anchor and hide it, as well as add the dialog structure outside of the `data-roll='page'` div -

```html
<a id='lnkDialog' href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"></a>
```

a#lnkDialog{display:none;}

```html
<div data-role="page" id="dialog" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d" class="ui-icon-nodisc" data-iconshadow="false"> 
     <h1 id="dialogHeadline"></h1></div>    
     <div data-role="content" id="text"></div>    
</div>
```

to display the returned JSON I have to add this in the success function of the $.ajax call.

```js
$("#lnkDialog").click();
$("#dialogHeadline").text('Success');
$('#text').append('<p>The location ' + '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">' + Name + '</span> has been added.</p>' + '<p>Details:<br> ' + 'ID: ' + ID + '<br>Address: ' + Address1 + '</p>');
```

I would rather store the HTML structure of the dialog in a var and call it in the `$('#lnkDialog').click();` if possible but can't get it to work.

```js
var dialog = '<div data-role="header" id="dialog" data-close-btn="right">//rest of HTML</div>';
$('#lnkDialog'.click( dialog );//doesn't seem to work, and how would I chain the .text and .append functions here?
```

I will need to access this dialog structure multiple times from multiple forms on the page. How do I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Why don't you use `$.mobile.changePage('#dialogID');` to open it without triggering clicks?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? How do I call it/use it? I replaced the $('#lnkDialog").click() with what you have above (using correct ID) and it went to a blank page with the URL appended with #lnkDialog

Comment: Once you finish appending items to the dialog through Ajax, call that function. This is the way to open it programmatically. Dialogs are pages but with data-role=dialog. `$.mobile.changePage('#id', { role: 'dialog' } );`

Comment: Using it this way: $("#dialogHeadline").text('Success');
                                    $('#text').append('<p>The location ' + '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;">' + Name + '</span> has been added.</p>' + '<p>Details:<br> ' + 'ID: ' + ID + '<br>Address: ' + Address1 + '</p>');
                                    $.mobile.changePage('#dialog', {role: 'dialog'} ); opens a blank page, then when I click on the blank page the dialog pops up. What am I missing? sorry for lack of formatting in the comments

Comment: Make an empty dialog outside page with id, append items and then call it.

Comment: Thanks Omar, I appreciate the help. That's basically what I did originally and am still getting unexpected results when I replace the .click(); with your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32186/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-omar)

Comment: I will give you a working example tomorrow.

Comment: Check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/kqh5r/